# How to compare a single cell to an entire column of a dataframe in python using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm getting this error: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." despite my best efforts to check the intermediate outputs (getting bools where expected, and the numbers are the correct data type I think, numpy.float64) I'm also using bit-wise operators.

I am attempting to count the number of times that each cell of a given column (M-1 m/z) is about equal to all the values of another column (observed M0 m/z) and then write that count to the row corresponding to M-1 m/z in a new column called "M-1 MSMS existence". I have the checked all the intermediate outputs and everything as far as I can tell is as expected (see the #print statements in the code).I'm also using bit-wise operators to avoid the error that persists. The if statement appears to be the issue and I've everything I can think up to this point (including reading docs and looking for similar issues on stack overflow). There's something else going on that alludes me. Thanks for any help.

Here's an abbreviated version of the csv I'm using:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
    for i in range(len(df)):
#    print('i=', i)
#    print("(df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] - (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100)", (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] - (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100))
#    print("df['observed M0 m/z']", (df['observed M0 m/z']))
#    print("bool", (((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] - (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) <= df['observed M0 m/z']) & ((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] + (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) >= df['observed M0 m/z'])))
    count = 0
    if (((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] - (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) <= df['observed M0 m/z']) & ((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] + (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) >= df['observed M0 m/z'])):
        count += 1
    df.at[i, 'M-1 MSMS existence?'] = count
```

i expect that the "M-1 MSMS existence" column will be populated with a number that corresponds the number of times that number was observed in the other columns rows. 0 if there were no values within the range (shown in the if statement) and 3 if there were 3 rows where "m-1 m/z" and "observed M0 m/z" were the same.

Comment: Heya, are you able to show us your expected output?

Comment: also provide a textual copy of your dataframe for others to copy not a picture.

Comment: Bare with me, I'm new at using stack overflow and not everything is intuitive. The format of the data was all wonky so I took a picture. You just need cols b and c if you'd like to manually enter it. I explained the expected output but I could show you explicitly. The new col made would be called "M-1 MSMS existence" row 1 would be 0, row 3: 0, row 4: 0, row 5: 0, row 6: 0 at least for the rows represented because for when checking each cell in column c against all rows of col b, they do not match (at lease within the error that I specific in the if statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the the soln is:

```
for i in range(len(df)): #include RT too
counter = 0
counter = np.count_nonzero(((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] - (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) <= df['observed M0 m/z']) & ((df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z'] + (df.at[i, 'M-1 m/z']/10**6)*100) >= df['observed M0 m/z'])) 
df.at[i, 'M-1 MSMS existence?'] = counter
```

I think the issue was that the if statement couldn't take the list of bools. So instead, we just count the trues as ones and use that number.